# Temp folder and file upload permissions issue

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, upload, guest-entries

Using Sprout Forms Plugin, and following the front end [file uploads example](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/front-end-file-uploads), I'm trying to use the famous [jQuery File Upload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to deal with batch of large files and get upload progression.

This works fine, but :

- How can I keep the files in a temporary folder before the form is submitted ?
- When user is a guest, I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error after each
  file upload (this happens even using [Guest Entries's plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries/tree/v1) from Pixel&Tonic, and with CSRF Protection is disabled) ;

Thanks for your help!